# Configuration in role based routing using BjyAuthorize is not working

Tags: zend-framework2, acl, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

Here is my bjyauthorize.global.php contents

```
<?php

return array(
'bjyauthorize' => array(

    // set the 'guest' role as default (must be defined in a role provider)
    // 'default_role' => 'guest',

    /* this module uses a meta-role that inherits from any roles that should
     * be applied to the active user. the identity provider tells us which
     * roles the "identity role" should inherit from.
     *
     * for ZfcUser, this will be your default identity provider
     */
    'identity_provider' => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\ZfcUserZendDb',

    /* If you only have a default role and an authenticated role, you can
     * use the 'AuthenticationIdentityProvider' to allow/restrict access
     * with the guards based on the state 'logged in' and 'not logged in'.
     */
      // 'default_role'       => 'guest',         // not authenticated
      // 'authenticated_role' => 'user',          // authenticated
      // 'identity_provider'  => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider',


    /* role providers simply provide a list of roles that should be inserted
     * into the Zend\Acl instance. the module comes with two providers, one
     * to specify roles in a config file and one to load roles using a
     * Zend\Db adapter.
     */
    'role_providers' => array(

        /* here, 'guest' and 'user are defined as top-level roles, with
         * 'admin' inheriting from user
         */
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Config' => array(
            'admin' => array(),
            'guest' => array()
        ),

        // this will load roles from the user_role table in a database
        // format: user_role(role_id(varchar), parent(varchar))
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ZendDb' => array(
            'table'             => 'user_role',
            'role_id_field'     => 'roleId',
            'parent_role_field' => 'parent_id',
        ),

        // this will load roles from the 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Doctrine'
        // service
        // 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\Doctrine' => array(),
    ),

    // resource providers provide a list of resources that will be tracked
    // in the ACL. like roles, they can be hierarchical
    'resource_providers' => array(
        // 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Resource\Config' => array(
        //     'pants' => array(),
        // ),

        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Resource\Config' => array(
            'Collections\Controller\CollectionsController' => array('admin'),
        ),
    ),

    /* rules can be specified here with the format:
     * array(roles (array), resource, [privilege (array|string), assertion])
     * assertions will be loaded using the service manager and must implement
     * Zend\Acl\Assertion\AssertionInterface.
     * *if you use assertions, define them using the service manager!*
     */
    'rule_providers' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Rule\Config' => array(
            'allow' => array(
                // allow guests and users (and admins, through inheritance)
                // the "wear" privilege on the resource "pants"
                // array(array('guest', 'user'), 'pants', 'wear')
                array(array('admin'), 'Collections\Controller\CollectionsController', 'index')
            ),

            // Don't mix allow/deny rules if you are using role inheritance.
            // There are some weird bugs.
            'deny' => array(
                // ...
                 // array(array('admin', 'guest'), 'collections', 'add')
            ),
        ),
    ),

    /* Currently, only controller and route guards exist
     *
     * Consider enabling either the controller or the route guard depending on your needs.
     */
    'guards' => array(
        /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled), it will block
         * access to all controllers and actions unless they are specified here.
         * You may omit the 'action' index to allow access to the entire controller
         */
        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'roles' => array('admin','guest')),
            array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'stuff', 'roles' => array('admin')),
            array('controller' => 'Collections\Controller\CollectionsController', 'roles' => array('admin', 'guest')),

            // You can also specify an array of actions or an array of controllers (or both)
            // allow "guest" and "admin" to access actions "list" and "manage" on these "index",
            // "static" and "console" controllers
            // array(
            //     'controller' => array('index', 'static', 'console'),
            //     'action' => array('list', 'manage'),
            //     'roles' => array('guest', 'admin')
            // ),
            array('controller' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array('admin', 'guest')),
            // Below is the default index action used by the ZendSkeletonApplication
            array('controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index', 'roles' => array('guest', 'admin')),
        ),

        /* If this guard is specified here (i.e. it is enabled), it will block
         * access to all routes unless they are specified here.
         */
        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route' => array(
            array('route' => 'zfcuser', 'roles' => array('admin', 'guest')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/logout', 'roles' => array('admin', 'guest')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/login', 'roles' => array('admin', 'guest')),
            array('route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => array('guest', 'admin')),
            // Below is the default index action used by    the ZendSkeletonApplicationarray('route' => 'zfcuser/register', 'roles' => array('guest', 'admin')),
            array('route' => 'collections/index', 'roles' => array('guest', 'admin')),
            array('route' => 'home', 'roles' => array('guest', 'admin')),
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

I have a database structures like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`display_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`state` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `username`, `email`, `display_name`, `password`, `state`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'test@test.com', NULL, '$2y$14$fL.K0rieXO.kHsHfOogH8Oaf..C.1GsYqEB49A3Dmxy9ZiMhWHx7.', NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_role`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_role` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`roleId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`is_default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`parent_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_role`
--

INSERT INTO `user_role` (`id`, `roleId`, `is_default`, `parent_id`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 1, 'admin'),
(2, 'guest', 1, 'admin');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `user_role_linker`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_role_linker` (
`user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`role_id`),
KEY `role_id` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user_role_linker`
--

INSERT INTO `user_role_linker` (`user_id`, `role_id`) VALUES
(1, 1);
```

I have modified column of user table according to this [issue](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/issues/174). And I have modified Mapper of [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) for user_id to id. It is working properly because it is not showing any error.

Even though there are no any errors I always get "403 Forbidden" for any module I visit (/user and /collections) except for login page (zfcuser/login) before login.

I have a doubt in database for user_role_linker table's data. I did not find proper documentation to enter roles data for user_role table in [BjyAuth library](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) . Suggest me is there any mis-configuration in config file or in database tables or anything else that is not mention here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the `user_role_linker` table, the feilds `role_id` should be `varchar` rather then `int`. I had the same issue. Check the following dump for the sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_role_linker` (
`user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`role_id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`role_id`),
 KEY `role_id` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
--   Dumping data for table `user_role_linker`
--

INSERT INTO `user_role_linker` (`user_id`, `role_id`) VALUES(1, 'admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly trying to do too much without knowing if you have the foundations setup correctly. Not a complete answer but I would suggest the following;

- Install Zend Framework Developer Tools (
  https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools ) once running it
  has a toolbar on the bottom of the page which will tell you what role
  you currently have. Its also useful for a bunch of other things.
  Assuming you have the appropriate role when you are logged-in, only
  setup one guard at a time. ie. you currently have both
  "BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller" and "BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route" setup
- You can run with just one or other of these to start, and when you have one running you can then test the other. Just remove or comment out the
  appropriate section in bjyauthorize.global.php.

Do note that the behaviour is that if you enable the guards everything that is not specified is blocked.

Without seeing your controllers and routes I dont know if some of the configuration above is correct but it might be safer to double check route names and use the fully qualified controller names eg. instead of

```
array('controller' => 'index',
```

try

```
array('controller' => 'YourModuleName\Controller\IndexController',
```

I hope this is some help.

Additionally, if you happen to end up using Doctrine ORM at some point https://github.com/manuakasam/SamUser is a great module to tie BjyAuthorize, ZFcuser and Doctrine together, easily.

Fin

Comment: I have setup role config and routes according you suggestion but output is still same. I have got this error while looking into Zend Framework Developer tool bar : 
Error You have to install or enable @bjyoungblood's Zend\Db Profiler to use this feature. Any idea about this?

Comment: This error is specific to only the DB Profiler, not important for the current issue - do you see to the right of that an icon indicating what user role you currently have? If not your setup may not be correct.

Comment: Yes there is an icon with label Guest. When I chick the icon, it shows: ByjAuthorize Identity Roles -1 Role: guest  Bu the role of current logged in user is not guest, its admin. guest role is always seen even if no user sign in (in login page).

Comment: You will have to go back over your setup again - when this will show the admin role if its installed and setup correctly

Comment: I had setup from composer. There is no chance of missing file. If any  file was missed it should show other php errors. Would you please tell me why I need to setup again with proper reason.

Comment: Please also take note of the code comments: "Consider enabling either the controller or the route guard depending on your needs." and "Don't mix allow/deny rules if you are using role inheritance." - never use both options in parallel.